# Vectorize loop dependent on its previous state

Tags: vectorization, logistics

We'll take this code:

```
n = 30;
x = ones(1, n);
for i=1:n
    x(i+1)=r*x(i)*(1-x(i));
endfor
```

The equation is just an example. 
Is it possible to vectorize it?

Comment: This is very easy to vectorize, since for `i=1`: `(1-x(1))=0` and from then on `x(i)=0`. You really need to give a meaningful example to get a useful answer ...

Comment: You're right... so, take an acceleration: $v_2 = v_1+a*t$ (suppose that you can't analitically integrate it)

Comment: `v = v_0 + a*dt*(1:n)`?